# Using list comprehension to "merge" a list within a list

Tags: python, list

So I have lists within a list:

```
woot = [['abc','efg', '4.3', '5.7', '80085'],['aba','bab', '1.0', '9.0', '3.0'], ... , ... ]
```

Every nested list is the same: first 2 elements are strings comprised of letters and the rest are strings comprised of numbers.

I'm trying to convert all the string numbers into floats and pool each respective nested list's string numbers into its own list (which ends up being a double-nested list) so the final result looks like:

```
final = [['abc','efg', [ 4.3, 5.7, 80085]], ['aba','bab', [ 1.0, 9.0, 3.0]] , ... , ... ]
```

So my approach is to use list comprehension to turn the string numbers into floats and split up those numbers and the letter strings in to separate lists and merge them.

```
bloop = [[float(x) for x in y[2:]] for y in woot]

bleep = [[x for x in y[:2]] for y in woot]
```

So I end up with:

```
bloop = [[ 4.3, 5.7, 8005.0],[ 1.0, 9.0, 3.0], ... , ... ]
bleep = [['abc','efg'],['aba','bab'], ... , ... ]
```

And here is where I break down and can't seem to wrap my head around "merging" these lists.

```
final = []
for i in bleep:
    final.append(i)
for i in bloop:
    final.append(i)
```

Unfortunately, this just puts the lists together as such:

```
[['abc','efg'],['aba','bab'],[ 4.3, 5.7, 8005.0],[ 1.0, 9.0, 3.0]]
```

Comment: That's done exactly what you asked it to...

Comment: Side note: `[[x for x in y[:2]] for y in woot]` is equivalent to `[y[:2] for y in woot]`

Comment: Another side note: try not to abuse list comprehension. It can save you a few characters in most occasions, but it may also make your code unreadable and slow.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I should be sticking to writing out the loops or using other functions? I'm trying to practice some of the mind hurdles of manipulating nested loops without resorting to using some magic tool from a library although now I'm starting to go stir-crazy with list comprehension as it seems to easy to lose my train of thought with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about:

```
final = [x[:2] + [[float(f) for f in x[2:]]] for x in woot]
```

Answer (score 3):

Simplify your logic:

```
final = []
for l in woot:
    adjusted = l[:2]
    adjusted.append( [float(x) for x in l[2:]] )
    final.append(adjusted)
```

---

> Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place.
>   Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by
>   definition, not smart enough to debug it.
>
> ```
>    — Brian W. Kernighan and P. J. Plauger in The Elements of Programming Style.
> ```
>
> *Reference: http://quotes.cat-v.org/programming/*

Comment: I take your point but list comprehensions are not too "clever". They are the meat and 3 veg of Python. In this case the list comprehension to produce the required output is trivial.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by not too "clever"?

Comment: @user155876 : it's a reference to the quote in this answer "writing code as cleverly as possible". My point is that list comprehensions are a fundamental Python language feature and that they are not necessarily clever. Sure, it's very easy to writing a list comprehension that is difficult to decipher, however, in this specific case, the required list comprehension is not too complicated at all.

Comment: I included the quote because the original problem was using two list comprehensions to make two lists, then try to merge them back together again. List comprehensions themselves are not a problem, when they are simple and straightforward. I actually upvoted Delgan's original answer as that looked nice and simple and easy to follow.  (and I kept one simple list comprehension in my answer at that!)

Comment: A pet hate of mine: the variable `l`. It looks too much like `1`. (I once found a program contaning `l`, `l1`, `l12` and `ll2`, the last of which was the bug!) That aside, I narrowly preferred this to the list comprehension, even though in general I love list comprehensions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list comprehension that produces your required output:

```
>>> [t[:2] + [[float(f) for f in t[2:]]] for t in woot]
[['abc', 'efg', [4.3, 5.7, 80085.0]], ['aba', 'bab', [1.0, 9.0, 3.0]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea below uses list comprehension and slicing syntax to split each sub list into a list containing sub-0, sub-1, and then a list of items from index 2..n. This is accomplished using the `+` operator of a `list` type.

I used `map` instead of an inner comprehension for brevity but there is no functional difference if you used `[float(ysub) for ysub in y[2:]]`.

```
woot = [['abc','efg', '4.3', '5.7', '80085'],['aba','bab', '1.0', '9.0', '3.0']]
print [y[:2] + [map(float, y[2:])] for y in woot]
[['abc', 'efg', [4.3, 5.7, 80085.0]], ['aba', 'bab', [1.0, 9.0, 3.0]]]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work :

```
final = [l[0:2]+[list(map(float,l[2:]))] for l in woot]
```

But maybe I cheat because I use `map` ...

Comment: Using `list(map())` isn't really any different from using a list comprehension.  It will produce the same result and really is not "cheating".

Comment: Of course, but he asked how to do WITH list comprehension and I'm not fully using list comprehension. I know it's not "cheating", it's just a different way to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

using your bleep and bloop

```
bloop = [[ 4.3, 5.7, 8005.0],[ 1.0, 9.0, 3.0]]
bleep = [['abc','efg'],['aba','bab']]
final =[]
for i in range(len(bleep)):
    final.append(bleep[i]+[bloop[i]])
print final
```

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of fine answers here, I just wanted to point out that the extend syntax is generally nicer. Also, try to avoid nesting list comprehensions. Its almost always clearer to just write a function for each level of the nesting and put one list comprehension inside each level. So I would do:

```
def process_list(l) :
    #processes the sub list
    new_list = l[:2]
    new_list.extend([float(x) for x in l[2:])
    return new_list

result = [process_list(l) for l in original_list]
```